# Regular expression chaining/mixing in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Consider the following:

```
my $p1             = "(a|e|o)";
my $p2             = "(x|y|z)";
$text =~  s/($p1)( )[$p2]([0-9])/some action to be done/g;
```

Is the regular expression pattern in string form equal to the concatenation of the elements in the above? That is, can the above can be written as

```
$text =~  s/((a|e|o))( )[(x|y|z)]([0-9])/ some action to be done/g;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, yes, variables in a pattern get interpolated into the pattern, in a double-quoted context, and the expressions you show are equivalent. See discussion [in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Composing-regular-expressions-at-runtime) tutorial.
(I suggest using [qr operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for that instead. See discussion of that [in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Compiling-and-saving-regular-expressions) as well.)

But that pattern clearly isn't right

- Why those double parenthesis, `((a|e|o))`?  Either have the alternation in the variable and capture it in the regex

  ```
  my $p1 = 'a|e|o';  # then use in a regex as
  /($p1)/            # gets interpolated into: /(a|e|o)/
  ```

  or indicate capture in the variable but then drop parens in the regex

  ```
  my $p1 = '(a|e|o)';  # use as
  /$p1/                # (same as above)
  ```

  The capturing parenthesis do their job in either way and in both cases a match ( `a` or `e` or `o`) is captured into a [suitable variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%3Cdigits%3E-($1,-$2,-...)), `$1` in your expression since this is the first capture
- A pattern of `[(x|y|z)]` matches either one of the characters `(`, `x`, `|`,... (etc) -- that `[...]` is the [character class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Using-character-classes), which matches either of the characters inside (a few have a special meaning). So, again, either use the alternation and capture in your variable

  ```
  my $p2 = '(x|y|z)';  # then use as
  /$p2/
  ```

  or do it using the character class

  ```
  my $p2 = 'xyz';  # and use as
  /([$p2])/        # --> /([xyz])/
  ```

So altogether you'd have something like

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $text = shift // q(e z7);

my $p1 = 'a|e|o';
my $p2 = 'xyz';

$text =~ s/($p1)(\s)([$p2])([0-9])/replacement/g;

say $_ // 'undef'  for $1, $2, $3, $4;
```

I added `\s` instead of a literal single space, and I capture the character-class match with `()` (the pattern from the question doesn't), since that seems to be wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Neither snippets are valid Perl code. They are therefore equivalent, but only in the sense that neither will compile.

---

But say you have a valid m//, s/// or qr// operator. Then yes, variables in the pattern would be handled as you describe.

For example,

```perl
my $p1 = "(a|e|o)";
my $p2 = "(x|y|z)";
$text =~ /($pl)( )[$p2]([0-9])/g;
```

is equivalent to

```perl
$text =~ /((a|e|o))( )[(x|y|z)]([0-9])/g;
```

As mentioned in an answer to a previous question of yours, `(x|y|z)` is surely a bug, and should be `xyz`.

Comment: 1) I am sorry I did not  formulate it accurately, all I wanted to know was the equivalency of the pattern. I did not look for the correctness of the logic of the expression. All I want to know if /($pl)( )[$p2]([0-9])/ is equal to /((a|e|o))( )[(x|y|z)]([0-9])/

Comment: Re "*all I wanted to know was the equivalency of the pattern*", Seeing as you didn't provide Perl code, there was no pattern. /// Re "*All I want to know if /($pl)( )[$p2]([0-9])/ is equal to /((a|e|o))( )[(x|y|z)]([0-9])/*", That is answered.